# add to cart nodejs mysql ejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, ejs

I want to add products to my cart, im using different routes for diff pages. So in my app.js file I have the routes that web pages requires however I cant get my id to display in my ejs views. Can anybody help? below is my code. I think the problem is with the id not displaying when I click the add to cart button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <% include partials/head %>
</head>

<body>
    <% include partials/menu %>

    <!--Product Cards-->
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Traverse through Database data-->
        <% productsData.forEach(function(result) { %>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="imgBx">
                <img src="<%= result.imagePath %>" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="contentBox">
                <h2><%= result.prod_title %></h2>
                <h3>$<%= result.price %></h3>
                <div class="size">
                    <h3>Size :</h3>
                    <span><%= result.size %></span>

                </div>
                <a class="add-cart" href="/addToCart/<%= this.id %>">ADD TO CART</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% }); %>

    </div>
</body>
<% include partials/script %>

</html>



router.get('/', function (req, res){
    var productId = req.params.id;
    var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {items: {}} );

    var sql = 'SELECT prod_id FROM product';
    databaseConnection.query(sql, function(err, results, fields) {
        if (err){
            throw err;
        } else {
            cart.add(results, results.id);
            req.session.cart = cart;
            console.log(req.session.cart);
            res.redirect('/shop');

        }
    });
});





// Import Routes 
var homeRouter = require('./routes/home');
var signInRouter = require('./routes/signIn');
var shopRouter = require('./routes/shop');
var registerRouter = require('./routes/register');
var signOutRouter = require('./routes/signOut');
var cartRouter = require('./routes/addToCart');

// Use Routes
app.use('/', homeRouter);
app.use('/signIn', signInRouter);
app.use('/shop', shopRouter);
app.use('/register', registerRouter);
app.use('/signOut', signOutRouter);
app.use('/addToCart/:id', cartRouter);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the `result` variable here:

```
<h2><%= result.prod_title %></h2>
<h3>$<%= result.price %></h3>
```

I would only assume you should use it to generate the add to cart link here:

```
href="/addToCart/<%= result.id %>"
```

over what you have:

```
href="/addToCart/<%= this.id %>"
```

however, if you are setting up the path parameter in a different place than your router is defined, you will need to use `var router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });` as specified [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.router).

Comment: Still doesn't work. Still giving 404 error page not found. I can get it to work manually by typing the route in but I cant get the add to cart button to work. SO I know the problem is with my ejs tag

Comment: what are you typing in manually, and what do you get when you right click on the link and select the "copy link location" (or equivalent) option

Comment: When I type the route “/addToCart/:Id” it works. However when I click on the a tag link that has that same route it doesn’t works. It brings up a 404 error

Comment: you type a literal `/:Id`?

Comment: Yes because I had to test it and see if it was the ejs tag that’s wrong

Comment: just to make sure, that is reserved syntax for express, and it will look at `:` when used like `/resource/:id/subresource` and parse into `(req, res) => { var id = req.params.id; }` so i dont think you can use `:Id` as literal url

Comment: Yeah, it still doesn't work idk what's the issue with it